# LinearLayout addview shifting animation

Tags: android, user-interface

When we add views to linear layout at particular index, then all views after that index get shifted. For example, I have linear layout with horizontal orientation. It has got five imageviews. When I want to add another imageview at 3rd position. So the imageview at 4th and 5th will get shifted to right.

I want this shifting to be animated. Can this possible? If yes, how can this be possible?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ViewGrop** for this adding view animation, change your layout to `viewGrop. new LayoutTransition();` By using this you can do.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please improve your answer a little (grammar, format) in order to help @Veer.